# Make Vue aware of data changed using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, vue.js

I've made a little script that appends some 'a' tags to a 'div', in order to enable the user to select the right value from a fixed list (too many options, so options will appear after user has written 3 letters or more).

I have a hidden field that is updated with the ID the user chose from the list.

I'm adding an onclick event with jQuery.

My problem is that Vue isn't aware of the values jQuery sets for the hidden fields, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Code below:

```
$('#form_product').on("click", ".choiceOptions a-participant", function (e) {

var id              = $(this).data("id"),
    participant     = $(this).data("participant"),
    inputId         = $(this).data("visualcontainer"),
    $visualInput    = $('#' + inputId);

// Set values for the shown input and the hidden input
$visualInput.siblings('input').val(id);
$visualInput.val(participant);

// Stop showing the participants
$visualInput.siblings('div').css('display', 'none');
})

vm = Vue.component('input-participant', {
template: '#input_participant',
props: ['id', 'label', 'value', 'maxlength', 'required', 'readonly'],
methods: {
    findParticipants: function (visualId) {
        var visualContainer = $('#' + visualId);
        var value = visualContainer.val();
        var list = visualContainer.siblings('div');

        if (value.length > 0 && value.length < 3) {
            list.html('<div>Keep typing...</div>');
            this.toggleParticipants(true, visualId);
        }
        else if (value.length > 2) {

            this.toggleParticipants(true, visualId);

            list.html('<div>Loading...</div>');
            this.$http.get(hazaar.url('api', 'participantLookup') + '?name=' + value
            ).then(function (response) {
                list.html('');
                $.each(response.data, function (key, value) {
                    list.append('<a-participant data-id="' + value.data.id + '" data-participant="' + value.data.participantName + '" data-visualcontainer="' + visualId + '">' + value.data.participantName + '</a-participant>');
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            this.toggleParticipants(false, visualId);
        }
    },
    toggleParticipants: function (doShow, visualId) {
        var $visualInputOptionsContainer = $('#' + visualId).siblings('div');
        if (doShow) {
            if ($('#' + visualId).val().length > 0) {
                $visualInputOptionsContainer.css('display', 'block');
            }
        }
        else {
            // A bit of a hacky way to do it, but it seems to work fine so far.
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $visualInputOptionsContainer.css('display', 'none');
            }, 150);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: You may try again with vue, currently this is just adding some vue to  jQuery which gives you no benefit compared to sole jQuery... Try read through some chapters of the [guide](http://vuejs.org/v2/guide), it's amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el:"#form_product"},
    data:{
        list:[]
    })，
    $(el).click（
        function（）｛
            vm.list=[]
})
```

For example, if you need to dynamic change the image here, you can use `vue`'s proxy instead of `jQuery`.

```
<div id="page" @click="proxyImage">
</div>
```

script

```
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#page',
    data: {
        topic: {}
    },
    method: {
        proxyImage: function (e) {
            if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'IMG') {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: could you add a bit of commentary in order to dumb it down a bit? thanks :)

Comment: <div id="page" @click="proxyImage">
</div>

Comment: `var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#page',
    data: {
        topic: {}
    },
    method: {
        proxyImage: function (e) {
            if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'IMG') {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
});`

Comment: My problem with this method was that all the clickable elements were added using AJAX, which means that Vue didn't recognize the click event.

I gave up on solving that problem and turned to jQuery :)

Comment: @JohnLajer You can bind the `click` event inside the `ready ` event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm pretty busy, so I've just hacked it so far, and then I'll get back to your solution :)

Thanks a lot, and have a nice day :)